# Log failover with Serilog

Tags: serilog

Is it possible, using Serilog, to log to a webservice of mine and if throws an error (no internet, for instance) to log to a RollingFile.
Should only log to RollingFile if WebService fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this yourself by creating a custom sink that wraps another `new RollingFileSink(...)` and only forwards events if the web service call fails.

To do this you'd implement `ILogEventSink` or, if the web service accepts batches, create a subclass of `PeriodicBatchingSink`.

Comment: I've been using this approach with a `FileSink` as a fallback. In order to accomplish this, I create a new `FileSink` and pass it into `MyCustomSink`. `MyCustomSink` forwards any events to the `FileSink` if the original delivery method fails. However, it appears that support for this approach is going away. In https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/commit/b660b51289599f2e6c9ce83dc6fdb5e8c81f1369, the public `FileSink` constructor was marked obsolete, indicating that you must use `.WriteTo.File`. However `.WriteTo.File` doesn't support this use case. Is there an alternative I'm missing?

Comment: Hey @blachniet - yes, sorry - I should have mentioned in that obsoletion message that you can now construct instances of any sink by using `LoggerSinkConfiguration.Wrap()`. If you need a hand and can raise a question here, send me a note and I'll help where I can.